# Example of nonvanishing higher inverse limits

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

It is well known that in the category of abelian groups, the limit over a cofiltered inverse system $\mathcal I$ of cofinality $\omega_n$ has nonvanishing derived functors only in degree $\le n+1$, i.e. $R^k\lim\limits_{\mathcal I} A_i$ vanishes for any system $A_i$ and any integer $k > n+1$. It is also known that $n+1$ is the best possible value.

However, I cannot construct any example such that $R^{n+1}\lim$ or even $R^2\lim$ does not vanish. Is there any simple examples?

Answer (score 0):

In

- Mardesic, Sibe. Strong shape and homology. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.

you will find examples in section 13.3. In the bibliographic notes in the end of the section the author writes

> It is difficult to find in the literature sufficiently simple, explicitly described, inverse systems $\mathbf X$ with $\lim^n \mathbf X \ne 0$, $n \ge 2$.

He also gives two references to two such papers.

Comment: Thanks. There seems to be no explicit constructions. The construction using projective resolutions is also rather indirect.